# AutoCAD to OSM, lossless

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, autocad

I'm trying to convert AutoCAD 3D data to OSM lossless, or close to lossless.

So far, the only way I can see it's possible is to convert from AutoCAD to SVG to OSM, according to OSM's WiKi.

Do someone have experience in using AutoCAD 3D data for OSM?

I'm going to use it in OSM3S, own hosted overpass-api.

I have the original data in MicroStation, so it's actually going from MicroStation to OSM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting DGN to DXF and then using ogr2osm seems to do it.